# Number of permutations when combining two sets?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have two sets $\{a_{1},\ldots,a_{K}\}$ and $\{b_{1},\ldots,b_{L}\}$, where I know that $a_{1} \leq a_{2} \leq \cdots \leq a_{K}$ and $b_{1} \leq b_{2} \leq \cdots \leq b_{L}$, but do not know the values of the $a$'s and $b$'s nor anything about the relationship between the $a$'s and $b$'s.

I want to know how many different monotonically increasing orderings of length $(K+L)$ are possible for the combined set of $a$'s and $b$'s with each element being used exactly once. In other words, if $C = \{a_{1},\ldots,a_{K}\} \cup \{b_{1},\ldots,b_{L}\}$, then how many different orderings $c_{1} \leq c_{2} \leq \cdots \leq c_{K+L}$ of the elements of $C$ can there be with each element being used exactly once?

I have always had difficulty with these types of combinatorial/counting problems, so if you could also describe your thought process in the solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: To be precise, $a$'s and $b$'s are element of what? Besides, do you admit a case like $\{a_1, \dotsc, a_K\} = \{a_1\}$, i.e., $a_1 = \dotsb = a_K$?

Comment: How about a recursive solution? Have you thought about it?

Comment: Is the answer not just $\binom{K+L}K$? In the final sequence of length $K+L$, you choose $K$ spots to be "$a$ spots" (and the other $L$ spots to be "$b$ spots"), and then the orderings of the $a_j$ and $b_j$ force all the individual positions.

Comment: The $a$'s and $b$'s are real numbers. If $a_{k} = a_{1}$ for all $k$, then there would be $K$ copies of $a_{1}$ which could each be used once.

Comment: I think Greg's answer is correct, does anyone else agree?

Comment: @GregMartin What about this case: $a = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and $b = \{3\}$? According to your formula answer is $4$. But shouldn't it be $1$?

Comment: @evencoil Greg's formula counts those solutions which preserves the relative ordering of the elements of both sets. But, as you see, that doesn't always give a correct solution. I think the answer is always $1$. Just tried a few cases. Still do not have a proof though.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous as to whether the actual values of the $a_j$ and $b_j$ are fixed, or whether they represent variables subject to the given inequalities. I rejected the former interpretation, because if all the values are fixed then of course the answer is always $1$ (we're just sorting numbers!). Rather, it's $1$ if there are no ties. Anyway, that seemed to me to indicate that the question must have the latter (variable) interpretation. Maybe the OP can clarify....

Comment: Yes the latter interpretation is what I had intended by saying I do not know the values of the $a$'s and $b$'s. A less ambiguous way would have been to say that they are variables. f.nasim's example in the way I intended to phrase the problem would give the orderings: {3, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3, 2} and {0, 1, 2, 3}, so 4 as Greg suggested.